# CustomTabPageIndicator multiple styles

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-styles, viewpagerindicator

I am using the viewPagerIndicator Library, specifically the TabPageIndicator. I have multiple activities and in each activity I need to use a different style for the TabPageIndicator. I am a bit lost on how to achieve that.

I have tried creating a custom class:

```
public class CustomTabPageIndicator extends TabPageIndicator {
    public TopTabPageIndicator(Context context)
    {
        this(context,null);
    }
    public CustomTabPageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context,R.style.customTabStyle), attrs);
    } 
}
```

But for some reason the default style is not overridden. Can someone please help on how to achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I checked out this link: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/issues/94

But for some reason the default layout and the custom layout are merged together.

Comment: Really desperate!! Can someone please point me in the right direction?